# How do I insert page breaks after each repeating section item in custom document merge templates with Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am create a custom Word merge template in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) and am having issues with page breaks.

I need two kinds of page breaks: one that will be in the same spot on every form after a "cost summary", and then second will be after each repeating section-"daily breakdown"- which could happen once or numerous times.

Each time I try to create a page break, more data moves to another page than I want.

Do parent-child relationships carry to the word document as they exist in the original Cognito form?  And how do I add page breaks below each repeating section item?

This is the form I am creating a custom merge template for:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/AmericanErectionLLC/AmericanErectionLLCDailyExtraWorkOrder

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/). The reason why your page breaks are not being honored is because Microsoft Word does not allow nested tables to be split.  The downloaded template utilizes tables to structure the document. As a result, you will need to move your section and repeating section content out of the main table so you can insert a manual page break after each section's content. The key is the page break cannot be inside a table but the content can be.

```
{each Items}
// content structured using a table
--------Page Break--------
{end each}
```